# Javascript onbeforeunload close browser window

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this tiny script for now that checks if any change is made on the form. If there is a change
then I set a flag to 'Y'. I call this function on onBeforeunload="changeConfirm()" places in the body tag. I know
I can't stop the user from closing down the window, but how do I make this scenario work where **he made a change 
-> decide to close the window -> Script alerted him -> User clicks cancel (Now I need to bring him back to the screen
instead of closing browser.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Flag= "";

function changeConfirm(){
if(Flag == 'Y')
 {
  var confirmStatus = confirm('Changes made. Dont want to save?');
 }
 else {
  alert("No changes were made " + Flag);
 }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: When I try this, the submit button prompts the user, "Changes made..."  How are you getting around this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 function confirmChanges() {
  if(Flag == 'Y')
   {
    if(confirm('Changes made. Dont want to save?')){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
   }
   else {
    alert("No changes were made " + Flag);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi niksvp.. Thanks for the solution. one question.. do I put in this function in body now?

Comment: @t0mcat - yes you can, but you have to put surrounding `script` tag and better in `head`.

Comment: @t0mcat - place the function in `head` and make a call to function `onbeforeunload` event of your `body`

Comment: Sorry got it working. Thanks :) Going to post a new question with modifications :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if ( Flag == 'Y' ) {
            return "Changes made. Don't want to save?";                         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jed, how do I make a call to this function? From the body tag? or just keep it inside <script> tag in the page and no need to call from body

Comment: Yep, just keep in `<script>`.

Comment: When I try this, the submit button prompts the user, "Changes made..." How are you getting around this behavior?