# Recommendations on how to prevent users from closing browser window (via onbeforeunload) AFTER the save button has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I've found numerous solutions on how to prompt the user about closing a window down before the data is saved but in my scenario, this one page is saving a lot of data and is slow (takes about 30 seconds) and this is AFTER the save button is clicked.  What we are finding is that the user is clicking the save button and then navigating or leaving AFTER clicking save.  Depending on the browser, whatever has been sent to the server isn't necessarily saved (looking at you Chrome).

I opted to use this solution and almost does what I need except even when I click the save button, I'm still prompted to save the changes since I'm leaving the page.  Its like I need to turn off the prompt and then turn it back on after some delay.  Is this even possible?

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if ( Flag == 'Y' ) {
            return "Changes made. Don't want to save?";                         
        }
    }
```

Comment: src of code above is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308441/javascript-onbeforeunload-close-browser-window

Comment: You should solve this through UI. Show some kind of progress bar or spinner to indicate that the operation hasn't completed.

Comment: Show a spinner in the UI and display a message saying don't close the browser and it might take 1 minute or 2 and when the saving is done, notify the user

Comment: We are already using the jQuery plugin, BlockUI, but our users are impatient and closing the window anyway.

Comment: In addition to the UI solutions, reducing the save time should also be considered (I know, easier said than done).  How is it that you are saving the data?  Maybe there are some optimizations you could make.

Comment: I'm new to the application and do not have a complete understanding of it yet.  Until I do, I just want to perform the duties requested. :)

Comment: When save is clicked, change the flag to 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a "save as you go" approach?... You can send small quick requests as the user progress in the whatever data input mechanism you have, and store that on a temporary file on your server, so when the user hits the "save" button or closes the browser window you only send a tiny request, quick enough to allow a safe browser disconnection. The server then just reads the temporary file and processes it as if it was send by the user in a single operation. May not be easy, but you'll get rid of quite a few headaches.

Comment: I proposed this solution, too, but if the user quits, then the client doesn't want ANY of the data.  They were very adamant about that.  LOL